# Token Mismatch Exception - Token changes for every call

Tags: php, laravel

I don't why its happening my whole project worked good till last week.Day before yesterday I couldn't load the site and there is no laravel error to shown.So updated the composer and packages via "composer update" command.From then
where ever I using post methods it projects the

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

error.

So I changed that method to get

```
<form method="get" action="{{action('SignupController@index')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
</form>
```

and i wrote in controller like

```
public function index()
 {
     echo Session::token();
     echo '<hr>';
     echo Input::get('_token');
 }
```

it gave result like ,

```
     kJqTndLBxOhyzUZd78Zj5IG2K5VIRVwDxepreHXE
     ----------------------------------------
     xKpqbnzb2DoRsw6ZtqTgHgcJFB9SixydkWjLhPJA
```

every time i reloading the page the new token comes.How can i get out of this ?

Comment: Then what you were expecting it over here

Comment: How shoud i get rid of the token mismatch error ?

Comment: When you were getting this error while using ajax

Comment: No ajax call,through forms only.

Comment: Check your app session configs, maybe it just not saving it! By default is File
`project/config/session.php`

Comment: @Froxz  `'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions')`, everytime i post a form new session file creating in the `storage/framework/sessions` and throws the exception

Comment: Check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-form-token-doesnt-match-session-token similar to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to apply the "web"-middleware to your controller / route.
The easiest way to do that is to create a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    // Your route definitions here.
});
```

The "web"-middleware initializes the StartSession class wich makes it possible to save sessions. You see what it does in the *app/Http/Kernel.php*.

Here are more possibilities to register routes:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware